# Raspberry pi 4 + share wifi to ethernet + pi hole

Tags: raspberry-pi, networkmanager, bridge, dnsmasq, pi-hole

I want to setup my raspberry pi 4 like this:

- Raspberry connect to wifi and share network to second router throught ethernet
- Run pi hole

I searched the internet to find out if it was possible to do something like this, but I found no answer. I tried to do this with NetworkManager but `dnsmasq` is blocking pi hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [linux-router](https://github.com/garywill/linux-router) to provide the Internet from the wifi interface to the Ethernet:

```
git clone https://github.com/garywill/linux-router.git
cd linux-router
sudo ./lnxrouter -i <Interface>
```